# Twitter android integration. How to show tweet without authentication

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, twitter-fabric

I have folowing scenario.

My client (local tv publisher) publishes some article and embeds tweet in it. ID of embeded tweet is sent through api to android application.

On android side i have integrated Fabric/TwitterKit and by following steps on twitter developers page i managed to show tweet in my android app on (i admit) easy way ([Show tweet exp](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/tweetui)).

Now i have published application to Alpha and noticed one "little" problem :-). TwitterKit was using my local twitter account to authenticate and to show tweets. If you dont have Twitter application installed or signed out of it, my show tweet functionality wont work..

This is [TwitterLogin](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login) explanation for obtaining TwitterKit auth token: 
*"When attempting to obtain an authentication token, the Kit will use the locally installed Twitter app to offer a single sign-on experience. If the Kit is unable to access the authentication token through the Twitter app, it falls back to using a web view to finish the OAuth process.
The simplest way to authenticate a user is using TwitterLoginButton, inside your layout..."*

What i want is to simply show content of tweet by given tweetID. No sending tweets, or any other action with it. Just show data from given url. Is it possible without authentication, or what should i do now, so that current implementation works without user authentication (or with some non-single-signon-inside-app authentication)

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have created MyApp extends Application class, and placed code below inside onCreate method. In application tag inside AndroidManifest file, added line:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:name=".MyApp"
```

onCreate:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =
                new TwitterAuthConfig(DeveloperKey.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, DeveloperKey.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY);

        Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig),
                new TweetUi());
```

It works so far, but i am not sure if this implementations is valid.
DeveloperKey.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY and DeveloperKey.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY are static values obtained from application created at apps.twitter.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Application Only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only).

That will generate a set of keys which can be used by the application. It won't be able to post messages to Twitter (because no user is associated with it) but you will be able to read Tweets.

If you build the keys into the app, your user won't have to sign in.

All the documentation is at https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

Comment: I am sorry for delayed answer. Still not sure do I have to use AppOnly auth. I saw few examples with twitter4j library, but none with official TwitterKit that works with ApplicationOnly auth. Please refer to my UPDATE 1 in question. Is this valid procedure?

Comment: Yes. It should work. Although if anyone gets hold of those keys, they could tweet from your account.

Comment: I dont know is it just me, but twitter implementation starts to be very frustrating. According to this post https://twittercommunity.com/t/application-only-auth-with-android/29149, Application Only auth from android is not even possible.
I am very close to decision to leave my consumer keys inside app . It would be readable to anyone who unpack my application installation file. I'll set "ReadOnly" permission to these keys.. so it wont be able to post tweets with it. Or to try my luck with twitter4j :)